# A strange output in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, error-handling

I have tried a simple code and found a strange error(wrt me)

it is something like s[10]
now i have put some number of values into this array.t

like s[0]=0;s[1]=1.s[2]=2 and all others are empty.

now i put a for loop to see how it goes and to my surprise after index 2, some random numbers popping up in output and idk why. It should be null and the loop should have exited but here, it gives me some output like 01248766575...

why is it happening? pls do help me if u know

Comment: The problem is that you have an uninitialized array.

Comment: In C++ objects aren't nullable by default. An `int s[10]` contains 10 integers with indeterminate values, they start off uninitialized. You cannot distinguish an `int` to which you never assigned a value, there is no such thing as a "null" integer.